# Elm: How can I find out the type of an Elm expression or a subexpression in elm-repl?

Tags: elm

How can I find out the type of an Elm expression or a subexpression in elm-repl ?

Haskell's `:type` or `:t` equivalent in Elm REPL?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Elm REPL automatically prints the type of whatever you enter. For example:

```
> "foo"
"foo" : String
> f = \a b c -> (a + 1, b ++ "!", c || False)
<function> : number -> String -> Bool -> ( number, String, Bool )
> f
<function> : number -> String -> Bool -> ( number, String, Bool )
> f2 a b c = (a + 1, b ++ "!", c || False)
<function> : number -> String -> Bool -> ( number, String, Bool )
```

As @amalloy points out, without an equivalent to GHCi's `:type` command, Elm REPL (as of 0.18) forces evaluation of an expression prior to showing you the type, which may be undesirable for expensive function calls. In its current version, there is no way around this.

Comment: You just showed a way around it! If you have an expression `E`, can't you just ask for the type of `\() -> E` and mentally erase the unit at the start?